# $or search using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find whether the user is entering a duplicate name and/or email address. I am new to Mongoose (and MongoDb for that matter), but based on what I have read, this appears to be correct. However, it returns true - no matter what. If I do a find for either one individually, not as an $or, it seems to work fine.

```
// check if user exists
var userExists = function(u, callback) {
  User.find({$or:[ {'username': u.username}, {'email': u.email}]} , function(err,user) {
    if (err) {      // err, so not sure if user exists
        callback(1);
        return;
        } 
    if (user) { // user, so return exists
        callback(1);
        return;
        } 
    //no error, no user
    callback(0);
    });
};
```

thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by 'it returns true'?  `User.find` doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: oops, added the whole function now.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense, thanks.  Can you add some logging to see what `err` and `user` contain in the callback?

Comment: oh, user is not coming back 'null' - it's just empty. 

err:null
user:

Comment: Right, `findOne` uses `null` for the no-matches case which may be a better fit for what you're doing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

updated method to check for `user.length` instead of whether it was null. If the document is not found by Mongoose (or MongoDB), it does not return null.

```
// check if user exists
var userExists = function(u, callback) {
  User.find({$or:[ {'username': u.username}, {'email': u.email}]} , function(err,user) {
    if (err || user.length > 0) {     // user does not come back null, so check length
        callback(1);
        return;
    } 
    //no error, no user
    callback(0);
  });
};
```

Comment: just remember that mongo.find() returns a cursor so  you just check the cursor length for checking if user is found or not

Comment: @Ajaybeni He's using Mongoose so `user` is an array not a cursor.